# Trying to install hbase in CDH-5.4.2

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I am using hadoop 2.6.0/CDH-5.4.2. I am trying to install hbase. For that I have to start Hadoop. So I used this command "start-dfs.sh". But I get error message "Command not found". Do suggest me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Namenode and datanode services running:

on master node:

```
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
```

on datanodes:

```
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-datanode start
```